# Table with clickable lines?

Tags: android

Is it possible to do a table like the sudoku's one and make the lines which divide the holes clickable? If it's not, what view should I use to make a grid with clickable lines?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want lines to be clickable? can you say some more info about your project?

Comment: I want to highlight the lines when I click them or when I programatically make them be bolder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// create a new TableRow

TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
row.setClickable(true);  //allows you to select a specific row

row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        System.out.println("Row clicked: " + v.getId());

       //get the data you need
       TableRow tablerow = (TableRow)v.getParent();
       TextView sample = (TextView) tablerow.getChildAt(2);
       String result=sample.getText().toString();
    }
});
```